# Is it possible to put attribute names in a different font than other text in WebStorm, PhpStorm, etc..?

Tags: android-studio, intellij-idea, phpstorm, webstorm

I'm trying to generate this effect, see as attribute names are in a different font style how to achieve this but in JetBrains IDEs:

[image]

Comment: Which "attributes"? Do you mean HTML (the ones in italic font)? If so -- have you tried the most obvious: `Settings/Preferences | Editor | Colors & Fonts | HTML --> Attribute name` ?

Comment: @LazyOne, yes I tried but there only options for bold & italic noting to change the font just for the attribute of an html element

Comment: Do we have any news from JetBrains?
I really like to use different fonts in my html attributes!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the current versions of the JetBrains IDEs, the text in the editor is always displayed in a single font. It's possible to use different font styles, such as bold and italic, for different elements, but it's not possible to use an entirely different font.

(Given that different fonts have different letter heights, allowing that would likely lead to weird effects when text that needs to be highlighted with another font is added or removed from the file you're editing.)